# node.js process.memoryUsage() ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just want to execute

```
console.log(process.memoryUsage())
```

in test.js with

```
node test.js
```

In my localhost it works perfectly, but on my server it generates the following error:

```
console.log(process.memoryUsage())
                ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
at Error (native)
at Object.<anonymous> (directory/test.js:4:21)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3
```

I'm using node v0.12.2. Any ideas why this error occurs?

Comment: do you have only one line code that console.log(process.memoryUsage()) ?

Comment: Yes, only that line. Works on localhost, but not on my server.

Comment: your localhost , linux or windows also your server should be linux ? may it cause because of server's users , i'm not sure can user permissions causes it? interesting..

Comment: Server: `Linux flores.ispgateway.de 2.6.32.53-grsec-pvops-xen-x64 #5 SMP Fri Jun 13 13:46:07 CEST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

localhost is done with MAMP. I'm using ssh to connect with a server from domainFactory, so i have no root access...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments , it might occurs because of user permissions in os.